# Bullet Physics Invalid Pointer on Free

Tags: c++, bullet-physics, irrlicht

I'm writing a game engine in C++ with Irrlicht and Bullet Physics. All of my Irrlicht code works perfectly, but upon creating Bullet Physics objects with new, and later freeing them, my program throws a `free(): invalid pointer` error.

Backtracing with gdb shows that the error is a libc `raise()` when Irrlicht tries to delete an Octree I am using for the game map: `irr::scene::COctreeSceneNode::deleteTree().`

The full gdb backtrace is:

```
free(): invalid pointer

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7455f25 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7455f25 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff743f897 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7499258 in __libc_message () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff74a077a in malloc_printerr () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff74a214c in _int_free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7bd3b69 in irr::scene::COctreeSceneNode::deleteTree() ()
   from /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so.1.8
#6  0x00007ffff7bd41ae in irr::scene::COctreeSceneNode::~COctreeSceneNode() ()
   from /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so.1.8
#7  0x00007ffff7bd4474 in virtual thunk to irr::scene::COctreeSceneNode::~COctreeSceneNode() () from /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so.1.8
#8  0x00007ffff7bf2706 in irr::scene::CSceneManager::removeAll() ()
   from /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so.1.8
#9  0x00007ffff7bf971e in irr::scene::CSceneManager::~CSceneManager() ()
   from /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so.1.8
#10 0x00007ffff7bf9c54 in virtual thunk to irr::scene::CSceneManager::~CSceneManager() () from /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so.1.8
#11 0x00007ffff7d45e5e in irr::CIrrDeviceLinux::~CIrrDeviceLinux() ()
   from /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so.1.8
#12 0x00007ffff7d45f54 in virtual thunk to irr::CIrrDeviceLinux::~CIrrDeviceLinux() () from /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so.1.8
#13 0x000055555556b97e in irr::IReferenceCounted::drop() const ()
#14 0x000055555556a88f in IrrlichtHandler::drop_device() ()
```

The code which seems to be the cause of the error is the initialization:

```
    /* PHYSICS SETUP*/
    btDefaultCollisionConfiguration *col_config = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
    btCollisionDispatcher *dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(col_config);
    btBroadphaseInterface *overlapping_pair_cache = new btDbvtBroadphase();
    btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver *solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;
    btDiscreteDynamicsWorld *dynamics_world = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(
        dispatcher, overlapping_pair_cache, solver, col_config
    );

    dynamics_world->setGravity(btVector3(0,-10,0));
```

and deletion of Bullet:

```
irrlicht_handler.drop_device();

    for(int i=dynamics_world->getNumCollisionObjects()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        btCollisionObject *obj = dynamics_world->getCollisionObjectArray()[i];
        btRigidBody *rb = btRigidBody::upcast(obj);
        if(rb && rb->getMotionState())
        {
            delete rb->getMotionState();
        }
        dynamics_world->removeCollisionObject(obj);
        delete obj;
    }

    delete dynamics_world;
    delete solver;
    delete overlapping_pair_cache;
    delete dispatcher;
    delete col_config;
```

The full code is on [Github](https://github.com/morgenm/PMC-Game/tree/4ea69584ee2a4cd58d22b1f06d61a4a76bd0b0ec).

Comment: C++ has smart pointers, any reason not to use them in your code?

Comment: @Vaillancourt the Bullet Physics example documentation did not use smart pointers and so I had little reason to. I am not sure that implementing them would solve this because this is some fairly basic usage of allocation. I might try implementing smart pointers but I'm afraid it would add unneeded complexity.

Comment: So what you say is that when you comment your bullet physics code, you don't get the error, but if you add it again, you have the error?

Comment: @Vaillancourt yes.

Comment: ..and you don't have access to a step-by-step debugger to figure out why?

Comment: @Vaillancourt the error occurs in the Irrlicht engine code itself, not the code I wrote. I'm not sure how to go step-by-step in the library's code but I'll figure it out and come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by switching from the latest github code to the release code. When I posted this question I didn't realize I was using the latest github code.